# How to solve link error in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linker, caffe

I want to build a Caffe project using make, and during build receive following error:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_size@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_footer_decode@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_uncompressed_size@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_buffer_decode@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_buffer_decode@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_end@XZ_5.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin] Error 1
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to build Caffe with Anaconda.  I have installed everything according to installation tutorial.  In fact I have used it before, and I can't understand what problem is now.  I'm not a very experienced Linux-user so I don't know how to trace it.

Can you give any hints how to solve it?

Comment: are you sure all prerequisites are installed?

Comment: @Shai ,yes, I did it all according to installation tutorial(actually I had it installed and used before, so now can't understand what problem is and even how to track it because I'm not very expirienced Linux-user)

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev`?

Comment: @Shai ,yes, I did. Tried even reinstall it(on Windows it sometimes helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04. This solved it:

```
apt install lzma-dev
```

adding **-llzma** to link libraries.

Answer (score 0):

just let people know the solution of 
"Just export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"" works for me. it is a pity to figure this out after 30 mins searching with ignoring this one at first sight..

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:
2 things worth to try:
In `~/.bashrc` file :

**(1)**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

**(2)**  comment out

```
export PATH="/home/jackie/anaconda2/bin:$PATH".
```

Explain:

> Sometime cmake will try to find library dependency base on python
>   execute (/home/jackie/anaconda2/bin/). This will cause some
>   ananconda's 3-rd library sneak in while linking.

P.S. It is also good to use `make VERBOSE=1` to make the cmake project, which can show the gcc compiling command line.

Answer (score -1):

I get a solution:

Just export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Comment: I added export into ~/.bashrc, but it did not changed error